# pandas rolling calc count function

Tags: pandas, rolling-computation

```
import pandas  as pd
import numpy  as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': np.arange(6), 'col2': np.arange(2, 8)})
```

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 3 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 3 | 6 |
| 4 | 7 |

and i want get column col3 if condition with after rolling.tail(3) and re turn count(col1>=3 and col2>=3)
the last result i want it `likes：`

| col1 | col2 | col3 | reason |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 3 | 0 |  |
| 1 | 4 | 1 | [(3>=3 and 6>=3)] |
| 2 | 5 | 2 | [(3>=3 and 6>=3),(4>=3 and 7>=3)] |
| 3 | 6 | nan |  |
| 4 | 7 | nan |  |

Hope to get your reply as soon as possible

Comment: Maybe you should update your post with the code you have tried so far. Maybe we answer as soon as possible... [Ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.